# Convert varchar string data to time format in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, procedure

I need to convert varchar string data to time format in mysql.

For example,

I have a varchar column in table which stores time. The accepted values should be like 9:30 AM  or 1200 PM. But currently it has either blank values or it has values like 9.30am or 12:00

There are many records like this, so cannot update manually.

Ithere any work around or function or procedure to do so?
please help.

Thanks

Comment: is there any specific format like 9:30 AM, 12:00 PM or any format like 9.30am,12:00

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) *MySQL* function to convert any string to a date.

Additionally you can use [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) to extract the time portion of a datetime. A combination of both function is used to convert an arbitrary date string to a datetime and then you can extract the time portion from it as a valid MySQL TIME.

By default MySQL functions follow standard format but custom format can be specified and if your values don't use the international formats you'll need to check with the documentation and provide the format your system is using.